# discord.js message.member.nickname always null

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

when i try the command, Reply **message.member.nickname** always return **null**, but the user have Display Name.

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'ping',
  execute(client, message, args) {
      msg.reply(`Hello ${message.member.nickname}`)
  },
};
```